# DateBox not work in my project

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

I don't know how  add datebox to my project.

I open page: [script builder](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/builder/) ,
I select version and component `FlipBox` and `TimeFlipBox` Modes,
I click download and save content as `picker.js`.

Next I click `CCS Version 1.45 Full` and save content to `picker.css`.

This files I add into header in my page:

```
<script src="~/Content/extension/datapicker/picker.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/extension/datapicker/picker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and i try use flipBox like:

```
<input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode" : "flipbox"}' />
```

but input is still only text. What i doing wrong?

Comment: first please check your url to picker.js and picker.css that these file are accessible. Next, Did you add jquery to your page.

Comment: yes, links url is ok, console no display any errors. I add jquery, jquery mobile and datebox.core before this scripts

Comment: Can you post all in <head> tag of your page and your web site url?

Comment: Yes, all scripts is head

Answer (score 0):

This code is work, Please include all jquery and jquery mobile in your page like this. 
Note: select include 'AMD Bindings' when download from jqm-datebox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQueryMobile - DateBox Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

    <!-- Change path of your downloaded css here -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.min.css" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="picker.css" />

    <link type="text/css" href="css/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/external/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/js/doc.js"></script>

    <!-- Change path of your downloaded scirpt here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="picker.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
          <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label>DateBox</label>
            <input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"flipbox"}' />
          </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Result]